# Uncaught TypeError: elasticsearch.Client is not a constructor elasticsearch.js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Thirld line of the function show `Uncaught TypeError: elasticsearch.Client is not a constructor`
I do not know why it is like this

```
function newAutocomplete(){
    var elasticsearch = 'elasticsearch';
    require([elasticsearch], function (elasticsearch) {});
    var esclient = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'localhost:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });
    esclient.search({
        index: 'user',
        body: {
            query:{
                match_all: {}
                }
            }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        var hits = resp.hits.hits;
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message);
    });
    $('#query_input').autocomplete({
        source: availableSuggs
    });
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/browser-builds.html ?

Comment: I did, but was not able to resolve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `elasticsearch-browser` instead of `elasticsearch`?

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet? I've just met the same.